# Pass arguments from command Line and from function inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I want know weather it is possible to pass arguments from command line and from the function inside a shell script

I know its is possible to pass a argument from command line to shell script using

```
$1 $2 ..
```

But my problem is my shell script needs to accept arguments from the command line as well as the  function inside the shell script .

find my shell script below

```
#!/bin/bash

extractZipFiles(){
  sudo unzip  "$4" -d "$5"
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "==>> Files extracted"
    return 0
  else
    echo "==>> Files extraction failed"
    echo "$?"
  fi
}

coreExtraction(){
extractZipFiles some/location some/other/location
}

coreExtraction

echo "====> $1"
echo "====> $2"
echo "====> $3"
echo "====> $4"
echo "====> $5"
```

I execute my shell script by passing

```
sudo sh test.sh firstargument secondargument thirdargument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward the original arguments with:

```
...
coreExtraction () {
    extractZipFiles "$@" some/location some/other/location
}
coreExtraction "$@"
...
```

To access the original script arguments from inside the function, you have to save them before you call the function, for instance, in an array:

```
args=("$@")
some_function some_other_args
```

Inside `some_function`, the script args will be in `${args[0]}`, `${args[1]}`, and so on. Their number will be `${#a[@]}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the arguments from the command line invocation to the function

```
coreExtraction "$1" "$2" "$3"
# or
coreExtraction "$@"
```

and add the other arguments to them

```
extractZipFiles "$@" some/location some/other/location
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba .. I dont want to pass the same arguments from the command line to the function inside the shell script , I need to pass a different argument to the the function inside the shell script ..Is there a way to do it .

Comment: Addressed this in my answer.

Comment: @SpencerBharath: Pass whatever arguments you need.